# matching both punkts regular expressions

Tags: javascript, forms, expression

I have such strong:

```
Nowowiejska 37, Tomaszów Mazowiecki, Polska
```

I would like to match with JS all strings with

```
any word, any word, Polska
```

How to do it? How to use and in regular expressions?

```
/.,/.,/Polska
```

?

Comment: Can you give specific examples? It's kind of unclear what exactly should be matched. Also, do you mean `strings` instead of `strong`?

Comment: I would like that 2 commas should be in the expression and on the and a word Polska f.e Słoneczna 6, 05-090 Raszyn, Polska

but as well as such string

Witolda Pileckiego 6, 02-723 Warszawa, Polska

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
function validate(string) {
    var splitstringarray = string.split(',');

    // check if the string contains 2 commas
    if (splitstringarray.length !== 3) {
        return false;
    }

    // check if the string ends in 'Polska'
    var suffix = 'Polska';
    if (splitstringarray[2].indexOf(suffix, splitstringarray[2].length - suffix.length) < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

var valid = 'Nowowiejska 37, Tomaszów Mazowiecki, Polska';
var invalid1 = 'Nowowiejska 37 Tomaszów Mazowiecki, Polska';
var invalid2 = 'Nowowiejska 37, Tomaszów Mazowiecki, Polski';

alert(validate(valid));    // returns true
alert(validate(invalid1)); // returns false
alert(validate(invalid2)); // returns false
```

A more elegant way would probably be to match a regular expression.

Comment: No I need that it should be 'string, string, Polska' string=any string I tried that but it doesn't work /[^,]*,[^,].Polska$/

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the comments. It actually matches the string you gave, and doesn't match the other two. A similar regular expression would probably look like `/,[^,]*,\s*Polska$/`. If I didn't get what you meant, please clarify.

Comment: Basically, both the `javascript` above and the `regex` will accept any string that contains two commas and ends in `Polska`. Did you try the code?